# Redux and Firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux

I've struggled to implement `react-redux-firebase` and `redux-firestore` into my app after configuring the redux store (struggled with this too, even though `redux-toolkit` simplified some things). Is it possible that I can communicate with firebase without using those two packages above? If so, how do I use `firebase` in any of my slices? e.g., auth slice below.

```
import {createSlice, createAsyncThunk} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'authSlice',
  initialState: {
    currentUser: null,
    isLoggedIn: false,
    isLoading: false,
  },
  reducers: {
    login: async (state, action) => {},
    registerUser: (state, action) => {},
    changeProfile: (state, action) => {},
    logout: async (state, action) => {},
    setCurrentUser: (state, action) => {},
  },
});

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const {
  login,
  registerUser,
  changeProfile,
  logout,
  setCurrentUser,
} = authSlice.actions;

export default authSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Yes, I did find a way to make it work.

Comment: Cool! Mind sharing the solution?

Comment: You can check the solution below. You can try variations of your own that can enable you to pass params to the query (making it a function).

Answer (score 1):

This is the query in a separate file.

```
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

export const getPopularProducts = firestore()
  .collection('POPULAR')
  .orderBy('count', 'desc')
  .limit(10)
  .get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {
    const views = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      views.push({
        key: doc.id,
        count: doc.data().count,
        product: doc.data().product,
      });
    });
    return views;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    alert('Error getting popular products: ', error);
  });
```

In the reducer/slice, import `getPopularProducts`.

```
import {createSlice, createAsyncThunk} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

import {getPopularProducts} from './../../lib/fetchData';

// Initial states
const initialState = {
  products: [],
  mainList: [],
  popular: [],
};


// Get popular products from firebase
export const fetchPopularProducts = createAsyncThunk(
  'prodSlice/fetchPopularProducts',
  async () => {
    const data = getPopularProducts;
    const {_W} = data;

    if (_W !== null) {
      return _W;
    }
  },
);


export const productSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'prodSlice',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    fetchData: (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = true;
      state.mainList = action.payload;
      state.products = action.payload;
    }
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [fetchPopularProducts.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.popular = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const {fetchData} = productSlice.actions;

export const selectProducts = state => state.prodSlice;

export default productSlice.reducer;
```

Then you dispatch `fetchPopularProducts` inside the `useEffect` hook. I cases where I needed a parameter for the query, I'd put the query inside  `createAsyncThunk`.